# Spool space issue using XMLAGG in a single table

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to aggregate all the NOTI_TEXT corresponding to NOTI_IDs. One NOTI_ID can have multiple NOTI_TEXT. I am using XMLAGG but it is running out of spool .

Below is the query:

```
select
        NOTI_ID,
        cast(XMLAGG(NOTI_TEXT  order by NOTI_TEXT_LINE_ID) as varchar(32000)) as NOTI_TEXT,
        NOTI_COUNTRY_ID,
        NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_ID,
        NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_TEXT,
        NOTI_SOURCESYSTEM_ID,
        CURRENT_DATE as TABLE_LOAD_DT
     from
        HC_PRD_D_RDDL_SDTB_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.SDTB_DM_SEV_111_NOTI_TXT_LINES_TEST_1
     group by
        NOTI_ID,
        NOTI_COUNTRY_ID,
        NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_ID,
        NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_TEXT,
        NOTI_SOURCESYSTEM_ID
```

All relevant stats have been collected. The skew factor of the source table is 1.5
Below is the EXPLAIN plan :

```
Explain select
         NOTI_ID,
         cast(XMLAGG(NOTI_TEXT  order by NOTI_TEXT_LINE_ID) as varchar(32000)) as NOTI_TEXT,
         NOTI_COUNTRY_ID,
         NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_ID,
         NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_TEXT,
         NOTI_SOURCESYSTEM_ID,
         CURRENT_DATE as TABLE_LOAD_DT
      from
         HC_PRD_D_RDDL_SDTB_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.SDTB_DM_SEV_111_NOTI_TXT_LINES_TEST_1
      group by
         NOTI_ID,
         NOTI_COUNTRY_ID,
         NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_ID,
         NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_TEXT,
         NOTI_SOURCESYSTEM_ID; 


  1) First, we lock
     HC_PRD_D_RDDL_SDTB_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.SDTB_DM_SEV_111_NOTI_TXT_LINES_TEST
     _1 for read on a reserved RowHash in all partitions to prevent
     global deadlock.
  2) Next, we lock
     HC_PRD_D_RDDL_SDTB_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.SDTB_DM_SEV_111_NOTI_TXT_LINES_TEST
     _1 for read.
  3) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from
     HC_PRD_D_RDDL_SDTB_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.SDTB_DM_SEV_111_NOTI_TXT_LINES_TEST
     _1 by way of an all-rows scan with no residual conditions, and the
     grouping identifier in field 1.  Aggregate Intermediate Results
     are computed globally, then placed in Spool 3.  The input table
     will not be cached in memory, but it is eligible for synchronized
     scanning.  The aggregate spool file will not be cached in memory.
     The size of Spool 3 is estimated with high confidence to be
     13,749,188 rows (64,456,193,344 bytes).  The estimated time for
     this step is 15 hours and 20 minutes.
  4) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of
     an all-rows scan into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally
     on the AMPs.  The result spool file will not be cached in memory.
     The size of Spool 1 is estimated with high confidence to be
     13,749,188 rows (148,092,503,948 bytes).  The estimated time for
     this step is 4 minutes and 10 seconds.
  5) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 15 hours and 24 minutes.
```

Having used this table for other queries we never found any anomaly. I want to check if it can be further optimized or any alternative to achieve the same .

Answer (score 0):

It's a large base table and a large aggregation and your system is probably not that big (spools are not cached).

Try to aggregate seperatly, .i.e. only based on the key column(s) (probably `NOTI_ID`) and then join back, this will remove those additional Group By columns from spool (`NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_TEXT` might cause this issue if it's a large VarChar):

```
select
   t1.NOTI_ID,
   t1.NOTI_TEXT,
   t2.NOTI_COUNTRY_ID,
   t2.NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_ID,
   t2.NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_TEXT,
   t2.NOTI_SOURCESYSTEM_ID,
   CURRENT_DATE as TABLE_LOAD_DT
from
 (   select
        NOTI_ID,
        cast(XMLAGG(NOTI_TEXT  order by NOTI_TEXT_LINE_ID) as varchar(32000)) as NOTI_TEXT
     from
        HC_PRD_D_RDDL_SDTB_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.SDTB_DM_SEV_111_NOTI_TXT_LINES_TEST_1
     group by
        NOTI_ID,
 ) as t1 
join 
 (   select distinct
        NOTI_ID,
        NOTI_COUNTRY_ID,
        NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_ID,
        NOTI_MAT_DIVISION_TEXT,
        NOTI_SOURCESYSTEM_ID
     from
        HC_PRD_D_RDDL_SDTB_0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.SDTB_DM_SEV_111_NOTI_TXT_LINES_TEST_1
 ) as t2 
on t1.NOTI_ID = t2.NOTI_ID
```